# How can I remove doubles without creating intersections?

Tags: python, mesh

I've got a mesh of a terrain. I'd like to create a simpler version that follows roughly the same shape. I've been using `Remove Doubles` to do this (which gives me a better result than the `Decimate` modifier), but have noticed that it can create intersections in the mesh, which causes me problems later on, particularly when using the `Boolean` modifier.

Original mesh:

[image]

When removing doubles (red areas are intersecting faces):

[image]

What's the best way to remove these intersections after removing the doubles (or preventing them from happening)? I'm scripting this process, so would love to hear of any solution that doesn't involve manually selecting visible/invisible faces. Thanks!

**Edit:** Here's [the Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eu3chu0q67dr7st/04361b17-29b6-4c20-992c-f45137591e2f.blend?dl=0) in case anyone is interested.

Comment: I don't think *Remove Doubles* is good option for simplifying a mesh (though it can sort of do that but you can't control the simplification); generally in order to do what you describe in first 2 sentences you'd use **Shrinkwrap** modifier to create a second, *roughly* the same but simpler mesh. Though I can't say that's a scriptable solution.

Comment: Did you try selecting similar > face angles?

Comment: @Mr Zak – thanks. I'd be happy to try an alternative method to `Remove Doubles`. I'll look into the Shrinkwrap (which I think should be scriptable, via `bpy.ops`), but haven't had much success with it so far.

Answer (score 3):

The mesh cleanup tools can help with this, especially [limited dissolve](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html).

[image]

Select all mesh elements in edit mode, then go to the Mesh --> Cleanup --> Limited Dissolve tool. Then triangulate all faces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

The larger the angle, the stronger the effect.

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods I use to simplify the mesh is *Selecting Similar*:

1. Go to Edit Mode.
2. Choose to work with edges (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>).
3. Select an edge.
4. Go to *Select* menu in 3D View > *Select Similar* > *Face Angles*.
5. Click <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*.
6. Repeat this process with Edges with different angles until you get the result you want.

The success of this method depends on the nature of the mesh and the edge you select, Blender will select the edges that have similar angles in between the two neighboring faces, dissolving the Edges will remove the Edges non destructively, so it will not create holes.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for this approach. However I don't think this is scriptable, given the need to select the right edge...

Comment: You are right it's not, I don't code, so I can't tell you how to right the script, only if you can set a range of angles "by coding" to select the edges, then selecting similar face angles, but I'm just conceptualizing here.